How do I combine two element path query expressions into a single query?
In the Microsoft documentation "Element Path Syntax for XML Report Data (SSRS)", I want a single element path query that will show me both Orders and Returns. Apparently, I can only get to show either Orders or Returns at a go - perhaps because Orders and Returns are sub elements of the Customer element. I am yet to get a code that retrieves both elements(Return and order details) from the customers.xml dataset. Is there a way I can combine the two queries I have written to show both elements - Returns and Orders - simultaneously?
here is the customer.xml dataset:
<?xml version="1.0"?>  
<Customers xmlns="http://www.adventure-works.com">  
   <Customer ID="11">  
      <FirstName>Bobby</FirstName>  
      <LastName>Moore</LastName>  
      <Orders>  
         <Order ID="1" Qty="6">Chair</Order>  
         <Order ID="2" Qty="1">Table</Order>  
      </Orders>  
      <Returns>  
         <Return ID="1" Qty="2">Chair</Return>  
      </Returns>  
   </Customer>  
   <Customer ID="20">  
      <FirstName>Crystal</FirstName>  
      <LastName>Hu</LastName>  
      <Orders>  
         <Order ID="8" Qty="2">Sofa</Order>  
      </Orders>  
      <Returns/>  
   </Customer>  
   <Customer ID="33">  
      <FirstName>Wyatt</FirstName>  
      <LastName>Diaz</LastName>  
      <Orders>  
         <Order ID="15" Qty="2">EndTables</Order>  
      </Orders>  
      <Returns/>  
   </Customer>  
</Customers>

Here is what I have tried:
Customers {}/Customer{@ID,FirstName,LastName}/Orders/Order{@ID,@Qty}|Customers{}/Customer/Returns/Return


I was expecting the output to be:
ID|FirstName|LastName|Order.ID|Qty|Order|Return.ID|Return.Qty|Return
Following are the outputs for order details and return details separately:
Customers {}/Customer/Orders/Order


Customers {}/Customer/Returns/Return



You can create a view in the database which is a temporary table.  Run the first query and then append the second query to the same table.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-view-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16
